# The indefinite article with the word "last"

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

Generally when "last" followed by a noun then the definite article is used. For example: "It was the last time I won." But in the news I came across this: "I can't lose and say 'I won a last time.'" why "the" is not used in the last example?

Comment: Source or more context? I wonder if it is grammatical or not. Also your examples are not similarly formed phrases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***The* last time** refers to the most recent occasion in a series of occasions,  and thus the final one, to date.

> The last time I went to the beach, there was a strong rip-current.
>
> When I saw him for the last time, he was committed to the idea of moving to Alaska.

***A* last time** refers to such a final time as one instance of many such last times.

> There will be a last time to visit a friend who is ill, a last time to kiss a lover goodbye, a last time to play Fetch with your dog, a last time to see the sunset or the sunrise. Life will have many last times...and first-times.

Comment: It seems to me ***the** [last time]* is optional in both your examples, but the choice doesn't affect the meaning. On the other hand, ***for*** in the second strongly implies to me that the speaker *never expects to see him again*, whereas without it he might just be referring to their most recent meeting (not normally *the last meeting **ever***).